# Java - Change label text on button press

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, jlabel, actionevent

***I have edited question per requirements***

So I want a label to change it's text when a button is pressed. But when I try to use setText() on the label when the button is clicked, it doesn't recognize it. Why is this?

```
public class SingleButton extends JPanel
    implements ActionListener {
    protected JButton b1;

    public SingleButton() {       
        b1 = new JButton("Axxxxxx"/*, leftButtonIcon*/);
        b1.setActionCommand("enableb1");
        b1.setEnabled(true);        
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        add(labelUpn);
        labelUpn.setText("UPN number here");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("enableb1".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            b1.setEnabled(false);
            labelUpn.setText("New Text");            
    }
}
```

Comment: Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. If I don't show you all the code you can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Write the same type of code with just **1** label and **1** button and nothing else.  If it reproduces the problem - you got your MVCE, if not - compare to your real code and find the difference.

Comment: Post a [mcve]. We wont look at github projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems with your code :

. You never did call `setText` on the label inside your `actionPerformed()` method.

. `JLabel labelUpn` is local to the constructor. Make it a class variable if you want to access it from within `actionPerformed()`

With that in mind, you can tell which button was clicked by casting `e.getSource()` to JButton, you can then get its text (which I assume to be the "UPN") by calling getText() on it.

```
public class ButtonDemo extends JPanel
implements ActionListener {
    protected JButton b1, b2, b3, b4;
    protected JLabel labelUpn;

    public ButtonDemo() {
        //...
        labelUpn = new JLabel("UPN number here on button press");
        //...
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
        JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
        labelUpn.setText(clicked.getText());
    }
```

Comment: Nice one, that was the problem. What do you mean by never call setText inside actionPerformed()? It it bad? Is using e.getSource() considered better?

Comment: My bad, bad wording on my part. I meant that you didn't call setText() inside actionPerformed() in the code you posted, not that you should never do it.

Comment: Ah yea. I had it left out as it didn't work so took it out! The problem was labelUpn needed to be a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is the solution of your problem.....

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class JLabelDemo {

    public JLabel labelText;
    public JLabelDemo() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("JLabel Demo");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLayout(null);

        labelText = new JLabel("StackOverflow");
        labelText.setBounds(50, 100, 150, 30);
        f.add(labelText);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Change Text");
        btn.setBounds(70, 200, 150, 60);
        f.add(btn);


        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                labelText.setText("Google.com");
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JLabelDemo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just read your code.
This might solve your problem.
You did not called the Button_name.setText("Text") in actionPerformed method
The Code is at
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1ppi

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment but it's a labels text I want to change, not the button text itself. Found the answer from another poster!